# Doxygen remove Macro Definition Documentation

Tags: doxygen

I use Doxygen version 1.9.3.
I have a c file :

```
#define l  20;
#define n  30;
#define k  40;

static void func1(int a, int b)
{

    printf("a %d",a);
}

int func2(int x )
{
return x;

}

long func3(char c)
{

    long temp = 0;
    return temp;
}
```

The file has 3 #define, after running Doxygen my output looks like this:
[image]

Is there a way to remove the Macro Definition Documentation section? I just want the Macro section.

doxygen -x Doxyfile output:

[image]

Comment: What is in your doxygen settings file different from te default settings (i.e. the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)? Where are the functions `func1` and `func2` defined as I don't seen them in the example but just in the documentation.

Comment: The main cause probably is that you use `EXTRACT_ALL=YES`, better would be to document the files (i.e. at least to add `/// \file` to the files.

Comment: The last edit with the image (bad idea, better use a cut and past of the text) confirm my assumption about `EXTRACT_ALL`. A look at git confirms that although a lot of changes have been made to optimize the detailed documentation the `EXTRACT_ALL` behavior has remained for the detailed documentation as a commit says `Always enable detailed section when EXTRACT_ALL=YES (same behavior as 1.9.1)`. so there is no way to removed the detailed documentation unless the ideas of my previous comment are followed.